# Change output of pause command in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a Windows batch script. By default, the `pause` command will pause the script and display the text *"Press any key to continue..."*.

How do I modify this text to display my own text to the user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Pause Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559738/changing-pause-message)

Comment: @Codemaker Your supposed duplicate was asked a year after I asked this question. If anything that question is a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You could hide the text from the `pause` command by using this:

`pause >nul`

Then you could echo your own message to tell the user it has paused:

`echo The batch file has paused`

So the full script might look like this:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!
echo The batch file has paused
pause >nul
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, I was wondering whether there was a way of actually changing the output text of the Pause command, not just a workaround to it.

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no way of changing that text.

Comment: KK, exactly what I afraid I'd hear. Thanks for your help anyway, though, mate. :)

Comment: Actually, I think this is the expected way of doing it. Since the PAUSE command doesn't accept arguments, you suppress its output, echoing your message just before PAUSE. I've seen batch files using this technique a lot of times.

Comment: Thanks for the input, LRMAAX. Present me is kinda amused at past me's pedantry for a "proper" solution. A few years of experience with code later and my standards have dropped and I'll accept a "hacky" method graciously. Still, it's good to know this is the commonly-accepted way to do things anyway.

Comment: @Hashim: I'm also amused, because I understand what you meant by that. Lack of time and looking for fast solutions makes workarounds and "hacks" a viable alternative in most cases. However, there's a downside to it, and I'm much more amused by the irony: this is a major reason why we have buggy software on the market, apart from human error. Experience apparently turns everyone into a "paper over the cracks" expert that goes for patching software again and again, instead of designing it properly right from the start. Me thinks the 2012 you was better than the current you, but that's just me...

Comment: @YinCognyto I'm no brilliant coder, but I feel as with most things, there's a healthy balance to be struck in the middle; over-reliance on hacks and patches encourages  unhealthy mindsets, ecosystems, and industries, but the kind of perfectionism that I had when young worships "rightness" for its own sake and is often debilitating and directly counter-productive. There's really something to be said for the bootstrapping/fake it 'till you make it method and building from that foundation incrementally, in contexts where you can afford to of course.

Comment: @Hashim: I'm also an amateur coder, so don't worry. I fully agree with you, with one slight note: perfectionism is only counter-productive in terms of time spent, in this case, with coding. In terms of efficiency, it's the most productive. I guess it depends on the goals you look to achieve. To me, it's not about worshipping "rightness" for its own sake, it's about making things the best you can. Of course, in the end, none of this matters, as all software gets replaced sooner or later by newer (but not necessarily better) ones :)

Answer (score 29):

Here's a one-liner

```
  pause>nul|set/p =any key to exit ...
```

It's slightly shorter (one less 'nul')
than Aacini's solution:

```
  set/p<nul =any key to exit ...&pause>nul
```

and, with the 'pause' first, I think that
it's a little clearer what the intent is.

With both

```
  cursor stays on the same line  
  ANY key works, not just 'enter'
```

Neither are as good, however, as the hypothetical

```
  pause/t any key to exit ...
```

It's hard to believe that 'pause' has survived
35 years without this ability ;-)

The solutions with 'echo' have the possibly undesirable
trailing new-line,
but do provide for multiple lines of text:

```
  Pause>nul|(echo  All your bases &echo  are belong to us &echo Press any key to die...)
```

bv

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you can do multiple and AND have no trailing new-line:        Pause>nul | (echo  All your bases &  echo  are belong to us & set/p =Press any key to die...)

Answer (score 9):

> "Not really what I was looking for, I was wondering whether there was a way of actually changing the output text of the Pause command, not just a workaround to it." – Hashim

Yes, you can! But you must be aware that PAUSE is an internal command of CMD.EXE program, so, to modify the message that PAUSE show, you must modify CMD.EXE file. To do that, you must use an editor that may modify binary files. I used [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) program via these steps:

```
1- Copy CMD.EXE file to a new folder created for this purpose: COPY %COMSPEC%
2- Edit the copy of CMD.EXE with XVI32.EXE program:
   2.1- Locate the message you want. Messages are stored in 16-bits elements with the high byte equal zero. To locate a message:
        2.1.1- In Search> Find> Text string> enter the message you want.
        2.1.2- Convert Text -> Hex
        2.1.3- Insert a zero after each letter-value
        2.1.4- Press Ok
   2.2- Modify the message for the new one. Modify existent letters only and keep zeros in place. Note that you can NOT extend any message.
   2.3- End the edition and save the modified file.
```

You may now run CMD.EXE to get the modified PAUSE message. I made a test of this procedure:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\Antonio\MYDOCU~1\My Webs\XVI32 Hex File Editor
>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\DOCUME~1\Antonio\MYDOCU~1\My Webs\XVI32 Hex File Editor
>cmd
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\DOCUME~1\Antonio\MYDOCU~1\My Webs\XVI32 Hex File Editor
>pause
Oprime una tecla para seguir. .
```

Notes to everyone that read this answer:

**NOTE 1**: Please, don't post that comment saying that modifying CMD.EXE file must NEVER be done! I think the same. I just posted this answer so the OP realized what he really asked for...

**NOTE 2**: The reviewing of CMD.EXE file with a text editor, like Notepad, is very interesting. You may see all the internal commands, interesting details (like =ExitCode and =ExitCodeAscii variables), all the error messages, etc. For example, these are the internal commands:

```
C O L O R   T I T L E   C H D I R   C L S   C M D E X T V E R S I O N
D E F I N E D   C O P Y     P A T H     P R O M P T     P U S H D   P O P D
A S S O C   F T Y P E   D A T E     D E L   D I R   E C H O     E N D L O C A L
E R A S E   E R R O R L E V E L     E X I T     E X I S T   B R E A K   F O R
G O T O     I F         K E Y S     M K D I R   M D     N O T   P A U S E   R D
R E M       M O V E     R E N A M E     R E N   R M D I R   S E T   S E T L O C A L
S H I F T   S T A R T   T I M E     T Y P E     V E R I F Y   V E R   V O L   = , ; + / [ ]      "     : . \ 


                                         P A T H E X T   P A T H     P R O M P T

                                                           F O R / ?   I F / ?     R E M / ?



            % s               % s
       % s 

         / A     / P     : E O F         
       f d p n x s a t z   D O
/ L     / D     / F     / R         I N     E L S E     ( % s )   % s       % s   % s % s
     % c % c     % s   % s                 & ( ) [ ] { } ^ = ; ! % ' + , ` ~
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not even going to risk editing CMD.exe, lol. I was just hoping it would be a parameter or something of `PAUSE` which allowed to do so. Besides, even if I did manage to modify the CMD.exe successfully, I'd still have to apply the same modification on all the machines I intend to use my script on, wouldn't I? Which would be next to impossible and completely impractical. Thanks anyway Aacini.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want not an equivalent solution, like this one: `SET /P =Any text you want < NUL` followed by `PAUSE > NUL`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to change the text of the `pause` command. However you might want to look at the `choice` command. You can change the text it prints. The only downside is that you need to provide a list of acceptable characters.

Comment: Just checked the `choice` command out, Michael.

A) I'm not really understanding how it would help me accomplish what I want to in this case, unless you're suggesting I use `choice` instead of the `pause` command?
B) It doesn't really matter anyway as I am running Windows XP, and the choice command isn't supported for it unless I download an extra resource kit apparently. See here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php. If I did download the extra resource kit to use it, I would have to do the same on all computers I'm intending to use my script on, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 4):

Already many solutions. Another variation that makes some sense:

```
echo Hit any key to continue...&pause>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

Another *dirty* solution would be something like this,

```
SET /P =Press enter to return to the menu . . . 
GOTO :menu
```

The benefit of this is that the cursor stays on the same line as the message, just like with the `PAUSE` command.

**The downside is that it only listens to the enter key.**

Comment: but you are limited to the `enter` key, while `pause` takes (almost) every key.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another trick

```
Pause. >nul | echo.  Press something to continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Windows 2000 (so, not XP) you can use the `choice` command which is far more powerful than either `pause` or `set /p`.

Besides being able to specify your own prompt text, you can also require the user to type a specific key, and only that key, instead of being limited to, and requiring, `[Enter]` to be pressed.

Also, you can prompt the user to press a number of different keys and take action based on which key was pressed.

Type `choice /?` for help, or read more about it here: [Wikipedia: choice (command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_(command))

Answer (score 1):

Since I dont see it suggested and every dog on the internet has had a go, but me.

This may not have worked under XP, as required by OP, but is valid for any newer system like my current Win7 :-)

Dirty version (no message) |keys ON does nothing, but block the press any key ...

```
timeout -1|Keys ON
```

can be used for message after
`@timeout -1|Keys ON&echo I'm back`

This one will pause and show a response until accepted then return to prompt/next cmd line

```
@timeout -1|Echo Hello Padawan %userprofile:~9%, Press a key, you can! 
:on any keys
@echo Welcome to the dark side
```

[image]

or boost that to the nth

```
@color 04&echo/&timeout -1|set /p="Hello %userprofile:~9%, you may press a key to proceed..."&color&echo  Continuing with process...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this!

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!
echo:
echo Press 1 to continue
set /p letter=

if %letter% == 1 goto a ;or instead of goto you could write start and the file or website you want to start
pause >nul

:a
cls 
echo BYE NOW!
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pause|echo text you want displayed
```

[image: Picture of cmd pause custom text]