# Changing Pause Message

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Ok, so you know how when you type up `pause` in CMD, it will say 'Press any key to continue...'. How do I change that to say something like 'Press a key to proceed...'?

Lastly, I was coding a batch file. I want to know what's up if I have something like:

```
@echo off
cls
pause
pause
pause
pause
```

It seems to skip round about to pauses When you press a key. I'm curious as to know the rules of which the pauses are skipped.
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the skipped PAUSE behavior. It always pauses 4 times, waiting for 4 key presses, as expected.

Comment: For skipped `PAUSE` commands, don't use arrow keys.

Answer (score 11):

Nearly the same as Deniz Zoeteman, except this version displays the blinking cursor on the same line as your custom message, as does the normal PAUSE command. The Deniz Zoeteman solution displays the blinking cursor below your message.

```
<nul set /p "=Press a key to proceed..."
pause >nul
```

Comment: Make sure to set the answer to the accepted answer if this is the thing you need :)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change the text displayed when a pause command is executed. It's bound to the Windows installation's language pack. The only thing you can do is not letting it say anything by doing `pause>nul`.
Of course, there's different ways to simulate `pause`; see the example from the other answer, where `set /p` is used. With `pause>nul` however, you can do this:

`echo Custom pause message`

`pause>nul`

And that should work.

And for pause commands skipping, that's most likely due to the key still being pressed down while the next pause command already executed (small guess though - I don't recall exactly if that's the behaviour of the command).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try

```
set /p=your message
```

Note: you will have to hit the enter key to continue versus any key.

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1:**

@echo off

echo Press any key to continue or Ctrl-C to abort.

pause > nul

**Option #2**

set /p=Press any key to continue or Ctrl-C to abort.

-->> I prefer the screen output of option #1.

Answer (score 0):

This is one practical application:

set /p=Press ENTER key to proceed or Ctrl-C to abort.

Answer (score 0):

A more personalised version could be

```
@color 04&timeout -1|set /p="Hello %userprofile:~9%, you may press a key to proceed..."&color
```

And you can mix that with a continuation

[image]

```
@color 04&echo/&timeout -1|set /p="Hello %userprofile:~9%, you may press a key to proceed..."&color&echo  Continuing with process...
```