# How to "modify" system ("pause") in C++

Tags: c++, windows, system

So I know that `system("pause");` pauses the program until one key is pressed while displaying this message: "Press any key to continue..".

My question is: can I modify somehow the message that is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `system(pause)` calls out to the external program `pause` in order to work! You could just do:

```
std::cout << "press any key.." << std::endl
std::cin.ignore(); // Wait for any key
```

Comment: ...except that `ignore()` doesn't typically return when any key is pressed, instead waiting for `<ENTER>` or a full buffer... would be better to prompt with "press <ENTER>...".

Answer (score 0):

No, since it is a system command. but you could probably write you own version fairly easily. After all, the entirety of what `pause` does is display some text and then wait for a key to be pressed.

Also, you might want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258822/change-output-of-pause-command-in-batch-file) which has answers that present alternative approaches.